# Convergence of difference equation to differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, convergence-divergence, numerical-methods, recurrence-relations

Starting with the difference equation:

$$f(x(t+dt),t+dt)= (1-a)f(x(t),t) + a f(x(t+dt),t)$$

where $x(0)$ is given and positive, $a\in(0,1)$, $f(0,t)=0$, and $f$ is increasing in both arguments.  This clearly defines a positive, decreasing sequence.

I would like to know conditions such that as I decrease the step size (i.e.   $dt\to 0$), that this sequence converges to the solution of the corresponding differential equation:

$$x'(t) = -\frac{f_t(x,t)}{(1-a)f_x(x,t)}$$

The domain can be taken to be $[0,x_0]×[0,1]$.  $f$ is nonnegative, bounded, and strictly increasing in both arguments, differentiable, etc.

Ideally would also like to handle the case where $x_0 = \infty$.

Thanks for any suggestions on how to approach this.

Any references or pointers to resources (for a relative beginner!) would be appreciated.

Comment: this problem has been studied (and still is), there are conditions to be met by $f(\cdot)$ and the underlying domain that in some cases lead to these reductions, i dont have references handy at this moment but i might post later

Comment: Yes, I assume it has been well studied (at least in some general sense).  Look forward to some guidance...

Comment: from a quick search look http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/194137/when-do-the-solutions-of-a-system-of-difference-equations-converge-to-solutions, http://web.stanford.edu/class/cme306/Discussion/Discussion1.pdf,

Comment: I know that in general we need "consistency" and "stability" for the result to hold.  I am hoping there are some standard conditions on $f$ that might guarantee this but am having trouble extrapolating from the literature cited.  (Most of the literature starts with a diff eq and then constructs a desirable recurrence relation, I am going in the other direction.)